# Web Scraping using Scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am supposed to do web scraping using an URL and the scanner class, and from the HTML code on the site pick out only numbers of energy consuption during the last 8 days. So I have an array that is 24x8 to fit all the numbers. I am using the .findInLine to identify the hour ex: 
I use the fist part here to identify the block with numbers for the fist hour.

```
while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null) in.nextLine();
in.nextLine() // skip rest of the line containing "00-01"

<td>00-01</td>
<td align="right"> 11872</td>
<td align="right"> 12146</td>
<td align="right"> 12861</td>
<td align="right"> 12561</td>
<td align="right"> 13493</td>
<td align="right"> 13386</td>
<td align="right"> 12732</td>
<td align="right"> <b>12249</b></td>
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to extract those numbers and put them into the array since I have 24 of these parts.

Comment: Use Jsoup for that

Comment: We have do do it this way for this assignment, unfortunatly

Comment: Are the numbers to be extracted in `<td align="right"> 11872</td>` for example?

Comment: Exactly, and there is 8 numbers for every hour

Comment: Can you explain the exact constraints ? Why do you really have to use a Scanner? can you use it just to grab the content as string or list of strings then apply custom code?

Comment: This is the first cours we have in programming, so we get the beginnings of the code from the teacher. And the assingment states that we have to use the .findInLine to identify the hour and then the eight numbers for each hour to get a passing grade

Comment: Have you collected this data `<td align="right"> 11872</td>` from the website already? Is this data part of  the variable `in`?

Comment: in is the name for the scanner, and collecting the data is the part I have trouble with

Comment: Has the URL been read and the data available in the scanner?

Comment: Yeah, that part works

Answer (score 1):

Given the input, the following would extract the numbers per line.

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    while (in.hasNext())
    {
      String str = in.nextLine();
      Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
      while (m.find())
      {
        //Change this to add to add to an array
        System.out.println(m.group());           

      }
    }
```

Comment: This would match "00-01" as 2 separate entries.Dunnot is that allowed whatsoever.

Comment: Agreed. The assumption is that the previous code did run to match 00-01. `while (in.findInLine("00-01") == null) in.nextLine();
in.nextLine() // skip rest of the line containing "00-01"`

Answer (score 0):

Given limited input from you I made it like that using pure scanner interface only:

```
public class Scrap {

private final static String HOUR_PATTERN = "<td>\\d{2}-\\d{2}</td>";
private final static String TD_DELIMETER = "\\s|<|>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(Scrap.class.getResourceAsStream("/input"));
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        if (!in.hasNext(HOUR_PATTERN)) {
            System.out.println(in.next());
            continue;
        }
        String found = in.next(HOUR_PATTERN);
        Pattern delim = in.delimiter();
        in.useDelimiter(TD_DELIMETER);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {// you wrote it is going to be 8 entries
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                if (in.hasNextInt()) {
                    res.add(in.nextInt());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(in.next());
                }
            }
        }
        in.useDelimiter(delim);
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
}
```

given input

```
blelblebll

<td>00-01</td>
<td align="right"> 11872</td>
<td align="right"> 12146</td>
<td align="right"> 12861</td>
<td align="right"> 12561</td>
<td align="right"> 13493</td>
<td align="right"> 13386</td>
<td align="right"> 12732</td>
<td align="right"> <b>12249</b></td>

<td>00-01</td>
<td align="right"> 11872</td>
<td align="right"> 12146</td>
<td align="right"> 12861</td>
<td align="right"> 12561</td>
<td align="right"> 13493</td>
<td align="right"> 13386</td>
<td align="right"> 12732</td>
<td align="right"> <b>12249</b></td>


<td>00-01</td>
<td align="right"> 11872</td>
<td align="right"> 12146</td>
<td align="right"> 12861</td>
<td align="right"> 12561</td>
<td align="right"> 13493</td>
<td align="right"> 13386</td>
<td align="right"> 12732</td>
<td align="right"> <b>12249</b></td>


<td>00-01</td>
<td align="right"> 11872</td>
<td align="right"> 12146</td>
<td align="right"> 12861</td>
<td align="right"> 12561</td>
<td align="right"> 13493</td>
<td align="right"> 13386</td>
<td align="right"> 12732</td>
<td align="right"> <b>12249</b></td>
```

produces

```
[11872, 12146, 12861, 12561, 13493, 13386, 12732, 12249, 11872, 12146, 12861, 12561, 13493, 13386, 12732, 12249, 11872, 12146, 12861, 12561, 13493, 13386, 12732, 12249, 11872, 12146, 12861, 12561, 13493, 13386, 12732, 12249]
```

It is based on yours input example, so it might now work on live markup.

Alternatively you could use `<.*?>` as delimiter and focus on number patterns only.